# Reshaping and Transposing NumPy Array to Match Specific Flattened Order

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape `(9,768)`, it is reshaped into a 3D array and then flattened. I am trying to find the combination of 2D operations like reshaping and transposing that will result in the same order when flattened. Here's an example

```
>>> m = np.random.normal(size=(9,768))
>>> A = m.reshape((9,12,64))
>>> A = A.transpose((1,2,0))
>>> a = m.T.reshape((12, 576))
>>> np.array_equal(a.ravel(), A.ravel())
True
```

A's axes have been transposed and the equivalent in 2D is a transpose followed by a reshape.

What would be the combination of 2D operations that can have the same effect as

```
>>> B = m.reshape((9,12,64))
>>> B = B.transpose((1,0,2))
```

I want to limit myself to 2d reshape, transpose, or flatten and avoid any operation that will create a 3d or higher dimensional tensor

Comment: What methods are you okay with since you have `m.T.reshape((12, 576))` working but don't seem happy enough with that?

Comment: Can't you just do `m.T.ravel()`?

Comment: @jared `m.T.reshape((12, 576))` works for tensor `A`, I'm trying to find the equivalent of `B`.  `m.T.ravel()` is not equal to `B.ravel()`

Comment: Oh, I missed that you changed the order of the transpose. So, which operations are you okay with?

Comment: Given `B = np.transpose(m.reshape(a, b, c), (1, 0, 2))`, then `np.stack(np.split(m,b,1)).ravel()` is equivalent.

Comment: @jared 2d reshape, transpose, flatten are fine. I want to avoid any operation that will create a 3d or higher dimensional tensor

Comment: What are you worried about? These operations are all fast.

Comment: @jared I'm actually working with [python-graphblas](https://python-graphblas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) The equivalents of reshape, transpose, flatten are available but not stack, split etc. I chose numpy to illustrate my use case

Answer (score 0):

In the first example

```
>>> m = np.random.normal(size=(9,768))
```

reshape to split the 768 dimension:

```
>>> A = m.reshape((9,12,64))
```

then move the 9 to the end; the 768 parts are still together

```
>>> A = A.transpose((1,2,0))
```

Ravel then makes 12*64*9

The alternative makes a (768,9), reshapes to (12,576), and then with ravel (12*576 = 768*9 = 12*64*9)

```
>>> a = m.T.reshape((12, 576))
```

Neither shuffles values in the 768 dimension, so the original split to 3d doesn't do anything.

```
>>> B = m.reshape((9,12,64))
```

This transpose makes (12,9,64).  Elements that were together in the (12,64) block are now split.

```
>>> B = B.transpose((1,0,2))
```

You can't make the equivalent without going to 3d or some other split.

It may be easier to visualize this with a smaller array, e.g.

```
m = np.range(24).reshape(2,12).reshape(2,3,4)


In [812]: m = np.arange(24).reshape(2,12).reshape(2,3,4)

In [813]: m
Out[813]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])

In [814]: m.transpose(1,0,2)
Out[814]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]],

       [[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [16, 17, 18, 19]],

       [[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])

In [815]: _.ravel()
Out[815]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3, 12, 13, 14, 15,  4,  5,  6,  7, 16, 17, 18, 19,  8,
        9, 10, 11, 20, 21, 22, 23])
```

Notice how the 12-15 sequence has been split off, and put right after 0-3.  You can't do that without making the (2,3,4) 3d array.

Your first A,a pair:

```
In [817]: m.transpose(1,2,0)
Out[817]: 
array([[[ 0, 12],
        [ 1, 13],
        [ 2, 14],
        [ 3, 15]],

       [[ 4, 16],
        [ 5, 17],
        [ 6, 18],
        [ 7, 19]],

       [[ 8, 20],
        [ 9, 21],
        [10, 22],
        [11, 23]]])

In [818]: m.transpose(1,2,0).ravel()
Out[818]: 
array([ 0, 12,  1, 13,  2, 14,  3, 15,  4, 16,  5, 17,  6, 18,  7, 19,  8,
       20,  9, 21, 10, 22, 11, 23])

In [819]: m.reshape(2,12).T
Out[819]: 
array([[ 0, 12],
       [ 1, 13],
       [ 2, 14],
       [ 3, 15],
       [ 4, 16],
       [ 5, 17],
       [ 6, 18],
       [ 7, 19],
       [ 8, 20],
       [ 9, 21],
       [10, 22],
       [11, 23]])
```

Notices how the 0,1,2,3,4,... line up in both

If I transpose the (2,12) to (12,2), I still need to break it into (3,4,2) to get 0-3 AND 12-15 blocks.

```
In [823]: m.reshape(2,12).T.reshape(3,4,2).transpose(0,2,1)
Out[823]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]],

       [[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [16, 17, 18, 19]],

       [[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```